# Jquery Cycle Plugin: Event on pause / continue?

Tags: jquery, events, cycle

I'm using the [jQuery cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) and want to display the current state of the slideshow (pause / continue) in a separate span.

Now I don't find an event that is triggered when the slidehow pauses or unpauses, to set the corresponding text.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was now way around modifying the original plugin source to hook into the internal pause/resume actions. I added them and will provide the changes to the original authors so that they can extend the plugin with this functionality if wanted.

Comment: Could you show your changes? They don't seem to be implemented in the Cycle plugin yet.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Mike Alsup, the author of Cycle, for a pause and resume callback just a few days ago. [He has implemented them already!](https://github.com/malsup/cycle/commit/3678467d4f2356524b26303901c602491d34bc08) How cool is that. Thanks, Mike!

You can [view a live demo here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pause-callback.html).

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    paused: function(cont, opts, byHover) {
        $('#status').html('paused');
    },
    resumed: function(cont, opts, byHover) {
        $('#status').html('running');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet it to wrap the code that handles the pausing to change the span's text.

```
function pauseCycle() {
  $("#cyclestatus").html("Paused");
  $("#cycle").cycle("pause");
}
```

Really, beyond that, you might have to actually edit the cycle plugin source.  There doesn't seem to be an easy way to hook into the pause/unpause process.